# How to translate all the country names provided by the Countries module in one shot?

Tags: i18n-l10n

I'm using Commerce Kickstart distribution. My site is not multilingual, it just uses French as the default language. I want to translate the countries names list provided by the [countries](https://www.drupal.org/project/countries) module from English to French.

After I enable the [Countries translation](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/countries/tree/modules/countries_i18n/countries_i18n.info) sub-module of this module, I would like to find a way to translate the names of all countries **at once** (in one shot), so that I do not have to translate them **one by one** (which seems to work fine).

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens for rewriting the question in a good way

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens you just motivited me to ask more questions, thank you again ;)