# Where is the button that will translate all countries from Countries module in all my 10 languages?

Tags: i18n-l10n

After installation of [Countries](https://www.drupal.org/project/countries) module I rest only 15 countries that I've translated one by one with Google Translate and my hands.

It's a pity cause my site is viewing and using in other countries too. But I need the automatic translation of country list in 10 site languages.

There is one more question that does not have an answer: [How to translate all the country names provided by the Countries module in one shot?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/145059/how-to-translate-all-the-country-names-provided-by-the-countries-module-in-one-s)

And google also shows this: https://www.drupal.org/node/2096581 But if I try to upload this translations it does not change anything cause by default language is russian.

One professional developer said that here I can get de database http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/ and using https://www.drupal.org/project/smart_ip I can translate my list of countries. But I do not believe in my power.

Please let me know if I can have solution of: How to translate countries list in several languages?

Answer (score 0):

For large tasks like this consider automating. and not just using "Drupal". Can you make a CSV file of your countries list? Then write a small Bash, PHP, Ruby or any script to ask Google for the translation(s) 1 by 1. Then given your new big CSV file of English + 10 other columns of languages. Loop through the file rows and do a database insert to Drupal to create the translations ...

From the final CSV of country terms translated I would then try to use the Feeds or Migrate module to import them to Drupal, if I didnt want to write much code.

Comment: very nice. all the tasks are new and I will look around your recommendations